# convert RDD[CassandraRow] to RDD[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

is it possible to convert RDD[CassandraRow] to RDD[String] ? if so , is there any disadvantage of working against the converted RDD ?

Comment: using `rdd.map` function you can transform to another form

Comment: there will be any performance penalty as my RDD will be huge ?

Comment: Need more detail, why you are converting an RDD of one form to another form and also RDD is distributed in multiple nodes. It is designed to handle huge data.

Comment: Actually My problem here is , I may have more than one data source that is C* and Text files. So thinking about generic approach without any performance impact

Comment: you can use sqlContext to data from Cassandra table, it returns an DataFrame, and when you read text file using sparkContext it returns RDD<String> and then you can convert that to DataFrame. Or if your text files are CSV, Spark 2.0 Supports csv data source, it returns an DataFrame by deafult.

Comment: can you update it in answer part so tat i can accept it

Comment: Its better to work with DataFrame than RDD, when you work with huge volume of data. DataFrame uses lot of optimization techniques using Catalyst optimizer.

Comment: Thank you so much. you mean to say that i can expect better performance from dataframe than core RDD ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sqlContext to read data from Cassandra table, it returns an DataFrame, and when you read text file using sparkContext it returns RDD and then you can convert that to DataFrame.

If your text files are CSV, Spark 2.0 Supports csv data source, it returns an DataFrame by deafult. Please see this.. https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html#new-features and https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/

**Update:**

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html